# Pass Word.Document to sub in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to pass references to Word.Documents to a sub in VBA (so that the sub can be run several times, always using the same 'target' word document, and different 'source' documents).

```
Public Sub StructuredFileParse(wrdDocSource As Word.Document, _
                            Optional wrdDocTarget As Word.Document = Nothing)

Dim wrdApp As Object

Set wrdApp = wrdDocSource.Application

If wrdDocTarget Is Nothing Then
    Set wrdDocTarget = wrdApp.Documents.Add
End If

wrdDocTarget.Activate
With wrdApp.Selection.PageSetup
    .LeftMargin = CentimetersToPoints(2#) 'Code fails here second time it runs
    .RightMargin = CentimetersToPoints(2#)
End With

'Do stuff

Set wrdApp = Nothing

End Sub

Public Sub TestSub()

Const ERR_APP_NOTFOUND As Long = 429

Dim wrdApp As Word.Application

Dim wrdDocSource As Word.Document
Dim wrdDocTarget As Word.Document

On Error Resume Next
' Attempt to reference running instance of Word.
Set wrdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
' If Word isn't running, create a new instance.
If Err = ERR_APP_NOTFOUND Then
   Set wrdApp = New Word.Application
End If
On Error GoTo 0

wrdApp.Visible = True

'Create a new word target file
Set wrdDocTarget = wrdApp.Documents.Add

'Set the first word source file
Set wrdDocSource = wrdApp.Documents.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & _
                    "AdvisorChargeQuoteSource.dot")

Call StructuredFileParse(wrdDocSource:=wrdDocSource, wrdDocTarget:=wrdDocTarget)

wrdDocSource.Close

Set wrdDocSource = Nothing
Set wrdDocTarget = Nothing
Set wrdApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

The first time I call the sub everything works as intended. However the second time I get an error (there is no error text, just a Ok/Help window and execution stops) at the end of the PageSetup part above.

Can anyone highlight the mistake(s)?

Thanks

Steve

Edit: Solution found at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/189618

Changed

```
With wrdApp.Selection.PageSetup
    .LeftMargin = CentimetersToPoints(2#) 'Code fails here second time it runs
    .RightMargin = CentimetersToPoints(2#)
End With
```

to

```
With wrdApp.Selection.PageSetup
    .LeftMargin = wrdApp.CentimetersToPoints(2#)
    .RightMargin = wrdApp.CentimetersToPoints(2#)
End With
```

So far, it seems to run every time without error.

Comment: The code you shared works fine without producing the error you mentioned. One potential error: do you close the file & word app after the main sub is finished (or produces an error)? note that be default, the word application is not visible - but will stay open unless you quit. so maybe the document you want to edit a second time is locked? check for instances of Winword.exe in the task manager and kill them. Use `wrdApp.Visible = True`...

Comment: I deleted it by mistake, but at the end of TestSub I have     Set wrdDocSource = Nothing
    Set wrdDocTarget = Nothing
    Set wrdApp = Nothing. Word closes the first time the sub is run when I close the docs manually. Then I get the error the second time I run the macro.

Comment: As @PeterAlbert points out, your code does not have a visible instance of Word, so how do you manually close the instance you've created.  Would you be able to show all the relevant code including setting the `Document` and `Application` to nothing?

Comment: @StevenBatham: In addition to `Set ... = Nothing`, you also need to `wrdDocTarget.Close` and `wrdApp.Quit` (of course before setting it to nothing)! Else, Word might stay open and lock the file - check in the Task Manager!

Comment: Hi, thanks all. I've updated the original post with more complete code. I want wrdDocTarget open at the end for user editing, and the second and subsequent run of the code should work whether the first word doc is left open or closed (in an ideal world :)). The error is "Run-time error ‘462’: The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable."

Comment: I believe I found the solution here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/189618 First post updated. Fingers crossed!

Answer (score 0):

Solution found at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/189618

Changed

```
With wrdApp.Selection.PageSetup
    .LeftMargin = CentimetersToPoints(2#) 'Code fails here second time it runs
    .RightMargin = CentimetersToPoints(2#)
End With
```

to

```
With wrdApp.Selection.PageSetup
    .LeftMargin = wrdApp.CentimetersToPoints(2#)
    .RightMargin = wrdApp.CentimetersToPoints(2#)
End With
```

So far, it seems to run every time without error.